# How can I make this decoration with TikZ in a section?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

It is possible to make a decoration in the sections or subsections of an article like in the image?

Comment: Hi and welcome. What's so special about it? Having a handwritten handwriting? Or be written on a school notebook? Or else?

Comment: This seem a [calligraphical font](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html)

Comment: The objective is to highlight each title with a snake, to make a working guide.

Answer (score 3):

You can put a tikz line before the header (of the section, subsection, etc.) and then use \vspace{} with a negative value to move it over the header.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt]
    \draw[rounded corners=8pt, pink] (0,0) -- (0.5,0.5) -- (0.7,0.0) -- (1.1,0.6) -- (1.5,-0.1) -- (1.8,0.4) -- (2.4,-0.1) -- (3.0,0.3) -- (3.5,0.0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{-1.3cm} % to move the line over the section header

\section{First section}

Your text goes here.

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt]
    \draw[rounded corners=8pt, pink] (0,0) -- (0.5,0.5) -- (0.7,0.0) -- (1.1,0.6) -- (1.5,-0.1) -- (1.8,0.4) -- (2.4,-0.1) -- (3.0,0.3) -- (3.5,0.0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{-1.2cm} % to move the line over the section header

\subsection{A subsection}

More text.

\end{document}
```

You might want to edit the line and depending on your font you would probably have to adjust the vspace for the line to appear where you want it, but this worked for me with a very bare bones article format.
[image: header line]

Comment: Thank you very much Plergux for the solution, I was having trouble with the titlesec package.